# Error While Trying To Install Ganache CLI

Tags: blockchain, solidity, npm-install, node-gyp

Im getting these errors when trying to install ganache globally on my windows 10, please help

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\leveldown
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.6 found at "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Cannot find module 'psl'
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Require stack:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack - C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tough-cookie\lib\pubsuffix-psl.js
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack - C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tough-cookie\lib\cookie.js
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack - C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\lib\cookies.js
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack - C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack - C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\install.js
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack - C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\node-gyp.js
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack - C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tough-cookie\lib\pubsuffix-psl.js:32:11)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\leveldown
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! Node-gyp failed to build your package.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! Try to update npm and/or node-gyp and if it does not help file an issue with the package author.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-10T10_32_11_739Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a virtualenv then install ganache cli, the errors seems to be with npm not recognizing ganache to link with the python on your system.

1. mkdir (project_name)
2. change into dir
3. run `python3 -m venv <name-of-env>`
   then, reinstall ganache cli.